# hide comments instagram api graph

Tags: php, facebook

```
curl -i -X GET \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/18126890926008983?access_token=XXXXXXX"
```

return

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-02-02T09:41:44+0000",
"text": "dfddfdf",
 "id": "18126890926008983",
 "__fb_trace_id__": "A9DiB2L0nXD",
 "__www_request_id__": "Ahu5iZRV7iniHS4uLarpO1o"
}
```

`POST /{ig-comment-id}?hide={hide}`

```
curl -i -X POST \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/18126890926008983?hide=true&access_token=XXXX"
```

return

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 10,
  "fbtrace_id": "A5u-LbyC-NG09SZM-pvtQWb"
},
  "__fb_trace_id__": "D5U4Wvtvp9C",
  "__www_request_id__": "A5u-LbyC-NG09SZM-pvtQWb"
}
```

the token is the same.
I tried to substitute the token on the page with the same result.
Help what could be the problem ?

Comment: sounds like your app doesn't have the required scope(s) to perform that action

Comment: @delboy1978uk  Do not tell me what to do about it ?

Comment: get an API token with the required scopes